# What sda numbur does my pc have

Tags: lenovo, busybox

I have a **Lenovo 300e** and right now I am in *BusyBox*, but I don't know what *sda* number I have, maybe somebody could help me

Answer (score 1):

1. Execute the command `sudo lsblk` should show you all the blocks.

   - lsblk - list block devices - from lsblk man page.
2. Another options is to execute the command `sudo fdisk -l` to show a list of the partitions.

   - fdisk - manipulate disk partition table - from fdisk man page.
   - -l, --list
     List  the  partition  tables  for the specified devices and then
     exit.  If no devices are given, those mentioned in  /proc/parti‐
     tions (if that file exists) are used - from fdisk man page.
3. You can watch this thread for more ways and examples [examples](https://vitux.com/4-ways-to-view-the-partition-table-in-linux/)

   - you can run all the commands with `grep` command to easier find your sda partition.
   - for example `sudo lsblk | grep -i sda`.
   - [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the command:

```
df -H
```

Here is an example from my machine:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           802M  2.1M  800M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        25G   17G  7.1G  70% /
tmpfs           4.1G   23M  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.2M     0  4.2M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6       952G  480G  425G  54% /home
tmpfs           802M  562k  801M   1% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see, my root partition / is at sda1 and I have a seperate /home partition at sda6. You likely have no seperate /home partition.